# Why does my code crash when I put in the line tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, database, search

I do not understand why, but whenever I include the line `tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar`, my code crashes.

Code is:

```
  let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)


var to = false
let ref = Database.database().reference()
var usersArr = [NSDictionary?]()
var filteredArr = [NSDictionary?]()
let cellId = "cellId"
var isSearching = false
var users = [User]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    search.sizeToFit()
    navigationItem.titleView = search
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    definesPresentationContext = true
    //Line below crashes
    //tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
   
    
    search.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.done
    
    
    ref.child("users").queryOrdered(byChild: "firstname").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        
        self.usersArr.append(snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)
        print(self.usersArr)
        
    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    
    self.table.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: self.usersArr.count-1, section: 0)], with: UITableView.RowAnimation.automatic)

}
```

I also received this error:
Terminating app due to uncaught exception Thread 1: Exception: "Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0. The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (0) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (0), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out)."

Comment: Check the console for the exception reason.

Comment: I got this error: ```Thread 1: Exception: "Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0. The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (0) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (0), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out)."```

Comment: The *number of rows* error occurs because `observe` works asynchronously and the row is inserted before the item is added to the data source array. And don't use *objective-c-ish* `NSDictionary` in Swift

Comment: thank you, it works now!